# What are the rules when you use the conjunction "and"?

Tags: conjunctions

I'm actually quite confused. Let's see...

I have eaten and drunk.

Or

I have eaten and have drunk.

I know the first one sounds... well, I think it sounds right, but...

Another one-

Azel is growing up and eating more.

Or

Azel is growing up and is eating more.

How do you know when to repeat the conjunction "and"?

Comment: The problem is not repeating the conjunction but whether we should repeat the auxiliary verb in the compound sentence.

Comment: The *full* versions of your sentences are *I have eaten and [I have] drunk* and *Azel is growing up and [Azel is] eating more*. But we normally remove those portions because they aren't needed for comprehension.

Comment: When the parts of the sentence either side of the conjunction contain different verbs or different tenses of the same verb the verb is specified in both parts. For instance "Azel has grown and is eating more". Otherwise the second verb is, usually, omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You'll usually want to reduce redundancy, for example I have eaten and drunk.  However, sometimes you'll want to have the extra heaviness: I have eaten and I have drunk.

But please avoid: I have eaten and have drunk.  It sounds unpleasant.

Similarly for the related examples.